# How to copy product names based on matched row names

Tags: r

I'm trying to copy "product" names from rows associated with a match of "row.names". I have a list of row.names and I want to match them to a list of all the "row.names" I have, a master list. I want to copy the associated "product" names, but only the ones that match my list "row.names".

I have tried using Excel for this but I can't figure it out. So I'd like to try R and I have a elementary knowledge. I know about variables, assigning variables, calling up specific data etc but I don't know how to move data around and manipulate it in "R".

If my table looks like this

```
Row.names
3285c
3219c
6794a
5673a
```

I would like to compare it to my master table below and copy the product info from that master table, by matching row.names

```
Row.names  Product
5747c      apples
3257r      oranges
3219c      beans
5673c      pears
```

The outcome will filter all the non-matches out and leave only the row.name matches and the product names behind.

Answer (score 0):

You really should give a reproducible example, meaning input, output and expected result.

```
products <- read.delim(text = "Row.names
3285c
3219c
6794a
5673a", sep = " ", header = T)

master <- read.delim(text = "Row.names Product
5747c apples
3257r oranges
3219c beans
5673c pears", header = T, sep = " ")

master[master$Row.names %in% products$Row.names, ]
#>   Row.names Product
#> 3     3219c   beans
```